# facing trouble while working with MSp430 timer and interrupts

Tags: timer, embedded, interrupt, msp430

I am trying to make a project with msp430g2553. The problem i am facing is while i am coding. What i have to do is:

1. I have enabled inputs on one of the pins of the msp. The timer starts on the rising edge of the input.
2. It counts to a certain value stored in TACCRO .
3. This continues for ever.

Now what i have to do here is:

1. Increment a variable c by 1 when the value in TACCRO is reached.
2. And also do some calculations with the value of counter stored in TAR register.

**Problem**
I am not able to figure out where should i write the code for calculation with the value in TAR, should i write it in ISR only or should i write it in the main code. 
Can anybody guide me with this?

**P.S i am writing a question here for the first time , so if more clarity is required please let me know.**

Comment: *When* should you read TAR?

Comment: I am reading it once the rising edge of the input comes , after stopping the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve at the end but, with the info you provide, I guess the simplest and easier way to do it would be using an ISR for the appropriate counter and writing your code there.

Keep in mind ISRs should be short and quick, so the processor can go on with other tasks. If your calculations are complex or the process is heavy, I would recommend storing the values in global variables, setting a global flag, and letting the complex calculations be done at the main code through a loop that checks and resets that flag.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can u (@asier) tell me one more thing . If i would likr to write two different ISRs then how would i be able to indicate in code, which ISR corresponds to which inerrupt?

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi This depends on the compiler, and is a different question.

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi as @CL. said, it depends on the compiler. For instance, in IAR it implies using a `PRAGMA` directive for defining the function you want to run for a precise interrupt vector. By the way, I guess you mean two ISR for **different**, otherwise: one interrupt can have only one ISR. (if you liked the answer, please mark as answered or upvote it so others can find it useful as well)

Comment: I mean for two different interrupts and i am using CCS v5.5.0

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with CCS, I use IAR, but it shouldn't be difficult to find it in the documentation looking for the appropriate keywords: interrupt handling routine, isr,...